# Is it safe to make use of PHP 5.3.0 new functions now?

Tags: php

As it depends on if the host support PHP 5.3, I wonder if all or enough many hosting company has upgraded their php environment to 5.3.

Do you already use these new functions in your project?

Comment: You can grab some stats if you want (a respectable task by itself) but that won't answer the *is it safe* question. What matters is what *your* hosting service has.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I maintain software that needs to run on **PHP/5.1.6** because that's what the customer's Linux dedicated server has and I maintain software that runs on **PHP/5.3.5** because that's what I installed in their in-house Windows server. That's why, before starting coding a new project, I always find out some basic environment specs.

As for development, I prefer to keep up-to-date with the PHP interpreter and reasonably conservative with my code (currently, **5.2.0+** if possible).

Answer (score 4):

> I wonder if all or enough many hosting
>   company has upgraded their php
>   environment to 5.3

It really shouldn't matter how many hosts have upgraded to 5.3, so long as the host you choose has upgraded to 5.3 then you'll be fine.

Answer (score 1):

It depends. If you are writing a script for yourself, then all that maters is that your server supports these features. If you are writing for others to use on unknown servers, then it might be an idea to make it very clear the scripts requirements or find work arounds.